# Matlab plot3 not working in Stereo Calibration and Scene Reconstruction example

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, stereo-3d, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to implement the example given on this page [link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html)
All parts of the codes are working nicely , but

```
    plot3(hAxes, x, y, z, '.', 'MarkerEdgeColor', reducedColorMap(i, :));
    hold on;
```

part of the code, which are the last lines of the code is not working , and the 3d reconstructed image is not coming. Its showing a blank white 3d plot, whih no values inside.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `x`, `y`, `z`, `i` and `reducedColorMap(i, :)` at that point in your code?

Comment: thanks, x y z are showing empty, any idea why? @Dan

Comment: And you're getting the correct images for `imshow(disparityMap, [0, 64], 'InitialMagnification', 50)` and for `showReprojectionErrors(stereoParams);`?

Comment: ya its coming..  @Dan

Comment: Then you must work your way backward from `x`, `y` and `z` and find which variables are the first to be empty.

Comment: ya got, x y z were negative values, and later they were finding points from 3 to 7, so x y z were zero matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the example code as is, or are you using your own images? If you are using your own images, and z's are negative, that would indicate that your camera1 is to the right of camera2. If you switch the images so that camera1 is on the left, the z's should come out positive. Alternatively, you can keep things as they are, and find the appropriate negative limits for z.

**Edit**: As of R2015b release there is a function called [pcshow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html) for visualizing point clouds.